# How can I recursively search a list of lists for an item, getting the "closest" match

Tags: c++, search, tree, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have a class "Class" which has a member std::list, I want to search that list/tree for an item, specifically an item with a specific name.
A basic representation of my class is as follows:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
class Class {
    std::string _name;
    std::list<Class*> _members;
public:
    Class(const std::string& name) : _name(name) {}
    void addMember(Class* member) { _members.push_back(member); }
    const std::string& name() const { return _name; }
    const std::list members() const { return _members; }
    Class* findItem(const std::string& name) const { ... }
};
```

I could just do something like this in Class::findItem:

```
Class* Class::findItem(const std::string& n) const {
    std::list<Class>::const_iteratior i;
    for(i=_members.begin(); i!=_members.end(); ++i)
        if((*i)->name() == n) return *i;
    for(i=_members.begin(); i!=_members.end(); ++i) {
      Class* cls = (*i)->findItem(n);
      if(cls) return cls;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, what I want to happen is for findItem() to return the "closest" item to the one searched from.
For instance, if this is my tree, with each letter representing one level in the list hierarchy, and each number representing the items "value". I want findItem(3) to return B(3), rather than C(3).

```
                        A(1)
                        |
        ----------------------------------
        B(2)                           B(3)
         |                                |
---------------------                   -----
C(3)             C(4)                    C(4)
                 |                         |
            ----------------           ----------
            D(5)  D(6)  D(7)           D(5)  D(6)
```

Comment: Is this is a homework assignment?

Comment: nope, personal project.
The class is actually an "object" class which has a "parent" and "children", just like the Qt QObject class. I'm using it an a small project for which Qt would be overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). As you access a node that isn't equal to the query value, you push that node onto the back of the queue. Process nodes from the front of the queue first. The first match you find will be the one closest to the root.

```
Class* Class::findItem(const std::string& n) const {
    std::list<Class>::const_iteratior i;
    std::queue<Class*> q;
    q.push(this);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        Class *c = q.front(); q.pop();
        if (c->name() == n) return c;
        for(i=c->_members.begin(); i!=c->_members.end(); ++i)
            q.push(i);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just want I'm looking for. And that code makes it simple to understand.

Comment: Just to note, std::queue had .front() not .top()

Comment: replaced top() with front() and added std:: to queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it [breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) style, i.e. first look at all the Bs, then all the Cs, etc., your match node will automatically be the closest.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking for a [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

*I think your question may be related to a homework assignment, so I won't divulge more details here.*

Comment: Heh, it's not a homework assignment, I'm a little too old for school.

Comment: My apology, it just looked like one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are interested in performing a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (Breadth Search First). The simplest way of implementing it is not by recursion but rather with a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing)) queue where you add the neighbor elements to the one you are testing at the end, and extract the first element from the queue to perform the next check.

The order of insertions would be [ A(1), B(2), B(3), C(3), ... ] and you will find B(3) before testing C(3).